# How do I pull the value of an attribute as it's being cached in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, galleria

I am trying to pass along both the `src` and the `rel` tag values. Here's the sample input.

```
<img class="image" src="example.jpg" title="" rel="value" />
```

The following is some code that is parsing all `<img>` tags on a page.

```
add: function(src, rel) {
    if (this.cache[src]) {
        return this.cache[src];
    }
        if (this.cache[rel]) {
            return this.cache[rel];
        }
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
        image.rel = rel;
    this.setStyle(image, {display: 'block'});
    if (image.complete && image.width) {
        return image;
    }
    image.onload = (function(scope) {
        return function() {
            scope.cache[src] = image;
        };
    })(this);
        jQuery(image).attr('rel', function() { image.rel } );
    return image;
},
```

However, this is my output.

```
<img src="example.jpg" style="display: block;" />
```

It's as if it's completely ignoring the `rel` tag. I need to pass the `rel` tag value from the old `<img>` to the new `<img>`.

Comment: The only important line is `jQuery(image).attr('rel', function() { image.rel } );` that is adding the attribute value, but I can't get it to pass ):

Comment: What happens when you set it directly, like so: `jQuery(image).attr('rel', image.rel);`

Comment: @Jacob - same result, not passing the rel value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is setting the properties. Not sure, but if the `rel` property doesn't map to the attribute, it won't show up.

Also jQuery muddles the distinction between attributes and properties a bit, so I'm not sure how it treats `rel`.

When you're setting the `rel`, add a `setAttribute()` call.

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = src;
image.rel = rel;
image.setAttribute('rel',rel);
```

Your original code does cause the `rel` property to be set, but not the attribute. This will actually set the attribute.

You should be able to get rid of this line:

```
jQuery(image).attr('rel', function() { return image.rel } );
```

---

**EDIT:**

Here's an alternate solution:

It seems that if you first set `image.rel = rel;`, the jQuery has no effect. Get rid of that line, and the `jQuery` code will work.

Comment: this is the first bit of code i've tried that actually returns in the `<img>`. However, it comes as 'undefined'.

Comment: @dmanexe: What do you mean? Did you try the `setAttribute()`?

Comment: @patrick yes, i tried that. here's a pastebin of what i have with your suggestion - http://pastebin.com/xP1iA7J3

Comment: @dmanexe: That code works for me. The `rel` attribute appears on the new image.

Comment: When I try your work discussed under edit, the `rel` tag is gone again. The closet I got was with the `setAttribute()`

Comment: @dmanexe: When you say *the closest*, what do you mean? What is the expectation, and what is the result?

Comment: ...note that you have `if (image.complete && image.width) { return image; }` so if the `if()` succeeds, any code *after* the `if()` will not run.

Comment: _"Closest"_ meaning I was getting nothing at all for a `rel=` tag, now I just get `rel="undefined"`. i need it to pull the original rel value, and before `rel` wasn't even showing up. I moved the conditional statement below the rest of the code.

Comment: @dmanexe: The conditional statement should be *before* the `image.onload=...` but after the rest. Strange that you'd get `undefined` for the `rel`. How is the code being called? You're passing an argument for the `rel` parameter, right? And what do you mean by the *original rel value*? The only `rel` value I see is what you should be passing when you call the function.

Comment: First off, thanks for all the help. You have been very helpful. What I mean by the original rel value is `rel="value"` mentioned in the original post. The code isn't "picking it up", if that's the right terminology. It's just passing `undefined`. The code is being called by another function, and since it's passing everything but the `rel`, my thought is that the bug is how the `rel` variable is being defined. It seems like the `src` is being defined properly, but `rel` doesn't get passed. (I'm new to programming, so there could be something big I'm missing)

Comment: With your code in there, with notes (the alert is a helpful tip - I will use that to check values in my future), the `rel` is still undefined. it's like it's not being defined properly from the cache, but `src` is >_<

Comment: @dmanexe: OK, so the issue must be with the other function. Could you provide the code for that function so I can see how it calls the `add()` function? By the way, `console.log(rel)` is a better way to check variables than `alert()`. Your browser likely has developer tools built in that will let you see the result in its console.

Comment: ...actually, I'm just going to take a guess and say that the other code is trying to get the `rel` attribute via `image.rel` (or something). If that's the case, replace that line with `image.getAttribute('rel');`. This will get the actual attribute since it seems that `rel` doesn't map from the attribute to the property.

Comment: @dmanexe: I see the code now, but I don't see how it is initially called. It seems like maybe it starts with the `load` method, but I'm not sure. How do you call this code so that it knows about your existing image?

Comment: Here's the whole file. it's galleria, a slideshow javascript plugin. I have to work with these constraints, so I just need this little blasted image to pass the `rel` tag along and I will be on my way. Here

Comment: @dman: Yeah, we need to go further back. The `add` seems to be called by `make` which seems to be called by `load`. You can see that each of these passes on a single argument of `src`. We need to somehow get the `rel` passed along. I just don't know where the image is first analyzed to get the `src`.

Comment: Basically, the way it works is that there's a `<div>` with a bunch of `<img>`s in it, and when I'm loading this code, it pulls the `<img>`'s `src` but from there, it won't pull *anything* else, because I can't define the `rel` the same way the `src` is defined.

Comment: PS - would you accept some cash for your time? I really appreciate this

Comment: @dman: Thanks, but no need. Anyway, to be honest, that is going to be a bit much to fully analyze. I think we're going to need to take a little more of a hackish approach. Would I be correct in saying that the `src` for each image is unique?

Comment: @dman: Well that was bad timing for a maintenance outage. Anyway, give this a try. http://pastebin.com/YArJeNtu It is now just selecting each image by its `src` attribute, and getting the `rel` that way. Not the most efficient, but should work. We can improve the selector a little if the images are in a container that has an ID. Give it a try and let me know how it goes.